# Does Zunimassa bonus works on Haunt?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Zunimassa's Haunt](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Zunimassa's_Haunt)

Mana Spenders include: Firebats, Grasp of the Dead, Haunt, Locust Swarm, Zombie Charger, Spirit Barrage, Acid Cloud and Piranhas.

What about haunt?

Also both haunt and locust swarm are DOT. So if DOT active does that mean that the zunimassa 6 set bonus improves damage by pet to 1500% will proc all the time?

Comment: Zunimassa's 6-piece bous works on Mana Spenders. Haunt is a Mana Spender (source: you). What about it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Haunt counts as a mana spender.

The fact that Haunt a DOT is irrelevant, since the Zuni's set bonus is active for 8 seconds at the time an enemy is hit with a mana spender.

Comment: Haunts with cripping death last an hour. So the zuni bonus pretty much last for a very long time?

Comment: @JimThio No, the 1500% damage amplification only lasts 8 seconds from when the enemy is attacked with a mana spender. The DOT has nothing to do with the Zuni damage amplification.